# ASP.NET Add Objects to website at runtime with Drag and Drop tools

Tags: c#, asp.net, object

I am starting on a project that will act as a visual inventory management solution.  Essentially a user will login to the application and be presented with a list of building maps.  After selecting a building they will be able to click on each room within the building (or mouse over).

Once in the Room view the goal is to have an invisible grid that can have objects added to the room to declare an object in the room and the rough location of said object.  I most likely could make each cell "editable" so that the user can click the cell and add the object to the database via the editor, but I was hoping for a slightly more visual option.

My question:  How can I approach creating an object legend which would allow a user to drag and drop from the legend onto the cell of the grid which would then pop-up or open an editor to fill in the remaining details about the specific object.

I am relating this to something like dropping a location pin on a Google Map or drawing a measurement.  The key difference being that the object created will require it's location on the map to be stored as well.

So end summary:  I am looking to be pointed in the direction of a tool set to allow me to create a generic object legend that can be used to generate new objects at "run time" by the end user.

Comment: `Javascript` is a direction. For other I afraid your question is too broad and you use "dangerous" word on StackOverflow _I am looking to be pointed in the direction of a **tool set**_ :). Asking for tools is "off-topic" here. May be you can ask more specific question

Comment: Thank you for the contribution.  I understand how the "tool set" is off topic... I suppose I was expecting specific library recommendations to look at that are built into the ASP.NET and C# languages.

I guess the specific version of my question is how do I make it so when someone drags, lets say an icon, and drops it to a location elsewhere on the page it would open an editor with that location information and the object that icon represents.  As mentioned this is like creating new objects at run time on an ASP.NET Web Application using a drag and drop system instead of a click to edit one.

Comment: This need to be done on the client side (as I said - Javascript). Then editor can be load from your ASP.NET Web Application, or do everything on client side and save only result of drag and drop to the server

Comment: Thank you Fabio!  You've been exceptionally helpful and I will look into using JavaScript for this task if it is definitely where we end up going.

I kind of figured it was going to end up using JS.  Being relatively new to ASP and C# (even knowing it's server side) I wasn't certain how much client side options were available.

If you want to put your response as an answer I will happily mark it as the correct answer and vote it up.